# adding button adjacent to a combo box in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a panel where I have 2combo boxes. I need to add a button next to one of the combo box. Both the combo box and button should come in the same line.Below is my panel

```
filterPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        renderTo: document.body,
          bodyStyle: 'padding-top: 6px;',
    title: 'Filters',
        collapsible: true,
        collapsed: true,
        shadow: 'sides',
        width: 400,
        frame: true,
        floating: true,
        layout: 'form',
        labelWidth: 150,
        buttonAlign: 'center',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'combo',
                id: 'xFilter',
                width: 200,
                listWidth: 200,
                fieldLabel: 'Filter',
                store: filterStore,
                displayField:'filterDisp',
                valueField:'filterVal',
                typeAhead: true,
                editable: true,
                mode: 'local',
                forceSelection: true,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                selectOnFocus:false
            },{
                xtype: 'combo',
                id: 'xStatus',
                width: 200,
                listWidth: 200,
                fieldLabel: 'Status',
                store: statusStore,
                displayField:'statusDisp',
                valueField:'statusVal',
                typeAhead: true,
                editable: false,
                mode: 'local',
                forceSelection: true,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                selectOnFocus:false
            }
        ]
    });
```

I need the button to come adjacent to the first combo box so that both the first combo and the button should be one the same line.
Could somebody please help me on this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

In ExtJS 4, since 'compositefield' is no longer available, you can use 'fieldcontainer' instead.

```
var config = {
    xtype:'fieldcontainer',
    layout:'hbox',
    fieldLabel: 'Combobox',
    items:[{
        xtype: 'combo',
        flex:1
        //rest of combo config,
    },{
        xtype:'button',
        text: 'Add New',
        handler: function(){
            //add new record
        }
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try using composite field

```
{
    xtype: 'compositefield',
    labelWidth: 120
    items: [
        {
            xtype     : 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Title',
            width     : 20
        },
        {
            xtype     : 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'First',
            flex      : 1
        },
        {
            xtype     : 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Last',
            flex      : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

or use [hbox](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.layout.HBoxLayout) or [column](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.layout.ColumnLayout) layout.